# Calculating column values, multiple columns in one command

Tags: r

I want to replace all column values for the SD, for example:

```
lol$`HP lvl 18` <- (lol$`HP lvl 18` - mean(lol$`HP lvl 18`)) / sd(lol$`HP lvl 18`)
```

Is there an easy way to do this for all columns at the same time?

Comment: `lapply(lol, function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x))`

Comment: thanks! exactly what I needed

Comment: @akrun did not! its awesome :D thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `scale` from `base R`

```
scale(lol)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
lol <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), 5, 4))
```